# CSS/Web design: how to create an oblique/sided button

Tags: css

How can one create a button on a website with each side being oblique (diagonals)?

I didn't find an example to show you but this is the closest I could find in 10 minutes:

http://cfl.ca/ (see the menu with tabs: News, Video, Schedule, Standings)

However, in my case, I need that sort of design for an independant button and not for a menu tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one (imperfect) way of doing it, though it's a little mark-up heavy:

```
<div class="button">
    <span></span>
    Some button text
    <span></span>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
.button {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button span:first-child {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1em solid #fff;
    border-left: 1em solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1em solid #f00;
    border-right: 1em solid #f00;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.button span:last-child {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1em solid #fff;
    border-right: 1em solid #fff;
    border-top: 1em solid #f00;
    border-left: 1em solid #f00;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.button:hover span:first-child {
    border-right-color: #0f0;
    border-bottom-color: #0f0;
}

.button:hover span:last-child {
    border-left-color: #0f0;
    border-top-color: #0f0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yhfqy/).

I'm not yet sure why the text-is aligned to the bottom of the `.button` element, but it seems to be a starting point, at least. (And any edits, or comments, left that explain/improve the answer will be welcome as soon as I get back to my desk...).

---

**Edited** to revise the demo CSS:

```
.button {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em; /* centering the text vertically */
}

/* other stuff */

.button span:last-child {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1em solid #fff;
    border-right: 1em solid #fff;
    border-top: 1em solid #f00;
    border-left: 1em solid #f00;
    margin-left: 1em;
    float: right; /* removes from the 'normal flow' */
    margin-top: -2em; /* aligns vertically with the top of the parent .button div */
}
```

[Revised JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yhfqy/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to Adam's (OP's) question (in comments):

> ...I'm trying to understand how you did it.

The idea is based around the simple premise that the join between borders is 45°, as illustrated with the following HTML/CSS:

```
<span id="box"></span>

#box {
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: red;
    border-right-color: green;
    border-bottom-color: yellow;
    border-left-color: blue;
}
```

With the result:

[image]

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8XrEE/).

That being the case if two adjoining borders are coloured the same two right-angled triangles are created (using the same HTML as above):

```
#box {
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: red;
    border-right-color: red;
    border-bottom-color: yellow;
    border-left-color: yellow;
}
```

Giving:

[image]

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8XrEE/1/).

In the example above I defined the height of the containing element (`.box`) as `2em`, and the borders of the contained `span` elements as `1em` (making the overall height `2em`, had I given the `span`s their own `height` (or `width`) the shape would have become more intricate:

```
#box {
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: red;
    border-right-color: red;
    border-bottom-color: yellow;
    border-left-color: yellow;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Giving (with `height`):

[image]

Or, using `width`:

```
#box {
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: red;
    border-right-color: red;
    border-bottom-color: yellow;
    border-left-color: yellow;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Giving:

[image]

Using both `width` *and* `height` allows for a partially-dissected box:

```
#box {
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: red;
    border-right-color: red;
    border-bottom-color: yellow;
    border-left-color: yellow;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Giving:

[image]

This could be useful for pseudo-3D frame effects, perhaps; particularly with `:hover` effects/changes.

I'm not sure if that's helped, much, but if you have any specific curiosities let me know in the comments, and I'll do my best to answer them. =)

**Edited** to add a pseudo-element, `::before`/`::after`, solution.

The HTML is simplified somewhat to:

```
<div class="button">
    Some button text
</div>
<div class="button">
    Some more button text
</div>
<div class="button">
    And yet more button text
</div>​
```

But the CSS is rather more verbose, not *complex*, but certainly there seems to be more of it:

```
.button {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 3em;
}

.button::before,
.button::after {
    content: '';
    border-color: #f00;
    border-width: 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.button::before {
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    right: 100%;
}

.button::after {
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    left: 100%;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.button:hover::before {
    border-color: #0f0;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}

.button:hover::after {
    border-color: #0f0;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

​[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yhfqy/164/).

Comment: Unfortunately this still has a rectangular hit area, although I have no better suggestion yet.

Comment: great fiddle, I'm trying to understand how you did it

Comment: @Adam, I've tried to explain some of the working behind my Fiddle (see the latest edit). Hopefully it'll give some insight into my methods/thoughts. Though if I've not answered your questions sufficiently, please let me know. And I'll do my best to help you further. :)

Comment: @David Wow, great explanations really! It is all clear to me now thanks to you. I definitely owe you one here ;)

Comment: @Adam: I'm glad to have been of assistance; you're absolutely welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough thirtydot posted a link to a tutorial for this earlier today: http://www.joecritchley.com/demos/slanted-nav/

It's for a nav, but the principle should be the same.

Comment: Note, does not work on internet explorer at all, I don't even see the menu when I checked. Using an image of a slanted button would be the safe way to go. (though hard coding overlapping with z-index on each individual menu bar item on that example site is something no self-respecting web designer should do)

Comment: Yeah, he does say on the site that's it's a proof of concept and more work is required to increase compliance, firstly by adding an image fallback. I thought it was worth posting though.

Answer (score 0):

You use oblique background images for each element, then overlap the elements to get the images to butt-up to each other visually. The only way to get around not having rectangle hit areas is to use an image map (which you probably don't want to use).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the most "techie" answer ever but [this site](http://css3generator.com/) can generate that kind of css for you (and browser compatible if possible)